# Different input different step response, so which one?

Tags: control-theory

I have a system (mobile robot to be more precise) which process input is voltage and output is distance traveled. And, I am doing PID tuning by using tuning rules, which requires step response of the system.

I realize that the step responses of 12V as input and 5V as input have different time constants and lags. In short, they produce different step response. So, which step response is the one I should take for my PID tuning?

[Step responses of different PWM values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I29fl.png)

[Normalized step responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1HHu.png)

Comment: If your system is linear time invariant, then any nonzero step response should have the same time constant. So could you maybe show the step responses that you have measured?

Comment: @Kwin van der Veen thanks for your reply. I have edited my post with step responses' image uploaded. I can see that my system is a bit linear at some point, but isn't LTI at all. My system is an integrating system btw. So which step response I should take?

Comment: are you sure that data is correct because the 95 line seems to always be above the 105 line?

Comment: Yes I saw that too. I will verify the data again. Thank you for pointing that out. But back to my original question, which step response is the one I should take? (my system needs to overcome set-point variation; moving from one position to another)

Comment: What do the step response look like when you normalize with respect to the step magnitude?

Comment: May I know what do you mean by normalize with respect to the step magnitude? The step magnitude you mentioned refers to input step magnitude?

Comment: Divide by the magnitude and yes, so the value in the legend.

Comment: Thanks for telling me on how to normalized. I have updated my post. So my there are many types of step response, so my system is non-linear? So single step response is insufficient to compensate set-point variation?

Comment: Does appears to be nonlinear yes. However which method where you planning on using, since I think most methods assume that the step response levels off?

Comment: I am planning to use AMIGO tuning rule. Yea you are right, most methods assume that way, but perhaps that's consider a research gap? Also, my process is an integrating process, another challenge for me.